# $\left | f(z) \right | \leq \left | z \right |^{k}$ then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function. Then if $\exists A\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $\left | f(z) \right | \leq A \left | z \right |^{k}$ then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.

The proof of the above theorem follows from the Taylor's theorem and Cauchy's estimate. My question is whether this result can be proven when it is the case

$f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \left \{ z_{1}, z_{2},...,z_{n}\right \} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

It is given that $f$ is analytic one to one and onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $j \in \{1,...,n\}$.

Since $|f(z)| \le A|z|^k$, $f$ is bounded in a punctured neighborhood of $z_j$.

Thus $z_j$ is a removable singularity of $f$. Hence there is an entire function  $g$ such that

$f(z)=g(z)$  for all  $z \in\mathbb{C} \setminus \left \{ z_{1}, z_{2},...,z_{n}\right \} $.